# How can I process the frame from OpenCV4Android camera in another thread

Tags: opencv, java-native-interface, opencv3.0, android

I am getting the frames from video camera using `OpenCV4Android` lib, I want to take the frame and pass it to `JNI` function, and get the result back to the android activity.

I don't want call that native function while displaying the camera frame, because the camera will become very slow.

Is it possible to take the frame in another thread and process it without slowing the camera ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to process the frames in a separate thread. But if you use preview surface, your camera live preview will not slow down due to processing of the frames. So maybe you don't have the problem at all. Please check.

Comment: Actually I am having this problem, I am using: `CameraBridgeViewBase`  
where :  `class CameraBridgeViewBase extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback `

Comment: Do you see that the live preview is jumpy when you spend a while processing preview frames? Which device do you use?

Comment: the device is LG Nexus 5